Asp.Net Core with React.js VS React.js and Asp.NET Core templates
I tried to create an app with asp.net backened and react fronted. All the tutorials said to use Asp.NET Core with React.js template, but I had only React.js and Asp.NET Core template.
What is the difference between this templates?

If I understand the question correctly, difference is build/deploy and two projects in one.  Using the ASP.NET with React project type makes building deploying a little easier and more of a one step process.

Most probably the templates are just separate ASP.NET Core project and separate project for React application. Similair to if you just create single ASP.NET Core project and then in other directory created React application with npm tools. Connecting the two is just the matter of setting backend URL (of ASP.NET Core) in React application.

What template should I use then? Which is better?
